# Transform this non-linear portfolio optimization problem into a quadratic optimization problem

Tags: portfolio-optimization, optimization, markowitz, transaction-costs

I have a portfolio optimization problem similar to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30939/portfolio-optimization-subject-to-transaction-costs) here, with a V-shape transaction costs such that we pay a fee proportionally to the sum of absolute rebalancing:
$$TC(\omega) = \frac{1}{2} |\omega-\omega_\text{old}|' \cdot \gamma$$
where $$\omega : \text{target portfolio to optimize},$$
$$\omega_\text{old} : \text{initial portfolio},$$
$$\gamma : \text{vector of average bid-ask spread}.$$

Essentially, my problem can be written as

$$  \omega_{opt} = \arg\min {\lambda \omega'\Sigma\omega + TC(\omega) - \omega'\alpha } \\  \text{ s.t. 
 }\omega_{i} \in [0,1], \forall i \text{ (no short-sell)}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i = 1, \\
\sum_{i=1}^n |\omega_i - \omega_{\text{old,i}}| \leq 0.5 \text{ (turnover constraint)}, \\
|\omega_i - \omega_{\text{old,i}}| \leq 0.1, \forall i \text{ (concentration constraint)}, \\
\beta = \omega' \Sigma \omega_{old}/\sigma^2 = 1 \text{ (beta constraint)}$$

I managed to solve this using `scipy.minimize` in `python`, but it is not really "clean".

**My question is**: can I transform this into a quadratic / convex optimization problem such that I can then use `cvxopt` to implement the solution?

My guess was to introduce some new variables $p$ and $q$ such that the $TC$ part becomes equivalent to:

$$\frac{1}{2} (p+q)' \cdot \gamma$$

s.t.

$$  p_i, q_i \geq 0, \forall i \\
\omega - \omega_{old} = p - q$$

such that the absolute term disappears, but then I end up with 3 times more unknowns: $\omega, p$ and $q$. Then I don't know if this is possible to reformulate that problem into a convex quadratic program of the form:

$$  \text{minimize } \frac{1}{2} x'Px+ c'x \\  \text{ s.t. 
 }G x \leq h\\
Ax = b \\$$
with $P$ positive semi-definite and feed it into the convex optimizer.

**EDIT:** I have reformulated the objective function with the change of variables using $p$ and $q$ to get:

$$\omega - \omega_{old} = p - q \rightarrow \omega = \omega_{old} + p - q \\
\Rightarrow \lambda \omega'\Sigma\omega + TC(\omega) - \omega'\alpha = \lambda (\omega_{old} + p - q)'\Sigma(\omega_{old} + p - q) + \frac{1}{2} (p+q)'\gamma - (\omega_{old} + p - q)'\alpha \\ 
= \lambda (\omega_{old} + p - q)'\Sigma(\omega_{old} + p - q) + \frac{1}{2} (p+q)'\gamma - (p - q)'\alpha$$

where in the last line I removed the constant term $-\omega_{old}'\alpha$,

s.t.

$$p_i, q_i \geq 0, \forall i \\
\omega - \omega_{old} = p - q \\
\omega_{old,i} + p_i - q_i \in [0,1], \forall i \text{ (no short-sell)}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (\omega_{old,i} + p_i - q_i) = 1, \\
\sum_{i=1}^n (p_i+q_i) \leq 0.5 \text{ (turnover constraint)}, \\
(p_i+q_i) \leq 0.1, \forall i \text{ (concentration constraint)}, \\
\beta = (\omega_{old} + p - q)' \Sigma \omega_{old}/\sigma^2 = 1 \text{ (beta constraint)}$$

The latter expression is close to the expected canonical form $\frac{1}{2} x'Px+ c'x$.

It also turns out that $\omega_{old}' \Sigma \omega_{old}/\sigma^2 = 1$, so the latter constraint would translate into $(p - q)' \Sigma \omega_{old}/\sigma^2 = 0$.

But then what? Do I need to do another change of variable or do I need to solve for $p$ and $q$, and in this latter case how? Do I need to stack up $p$ and $q$ in a vector $x$ of size $2n$, with $n$ being the number of assets (and also the dimension of $\omega$)?

Comment: Hi: Check out andre perold's early paper on optimization with transaction costs. I can't remember for sure but there may be in something in there related to your question.

Comment: Does the analytical solution from this question (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30549/maximum-certainty-equivalent-portfolio-with-transaction-costs?noredirect=1&lq=1) help you? Ignoring no-short sale constraints would yield a quadratic optimization problem in which transaction costs can be incorporated via any Lasso-like regression problem.

Comment: You are doing it correctly. Just formulate it in the canonical form. You will see it all works out. You can of course substitute out $\omega$ with $p-q$ and eliminate one variable to gain some speed. But that is an extra choice not a necessity.

Comment: I have edited my questions with some additional steps after the change of variable for $\omega$. @Hans I guess I am missing a small final step here... Could you please help?

Comment: Where did the transaction cost term go in the objective function? You need to put the constraints in as well.

Comment: @Hans: It looks like TC($\omega$) is there but the $-\omega^{\prime} \times \alpha$ from the original objective function was left out.

Comment: Also, is the $\beta$ constraint correct. There are two different $\omega$ terms in it which I don't follow. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: Yes. I do not understand either where these mistakes come from. It is just simple substitution...

Comment: But anyway, yes, you need to stack up all the variables to put into the canonical form.

Comment: @Hans and mark leeds Sorry I made a mistake, I have rewriten additional steps to make it clearer as well, on top of the constraints. Let me know if additional remarks

Comment: Why does $(p - q)' \Sigma \omega_{old}/\sigma^2 = 0 \implies p = q$? Do you know how to carry it from here?

Comment: I thought this was a property of positive semi-definite matrix, but it seems my algebra is a little bit rusty... I will try to figure it out but the $(\omega_old + p - q)$ in the variance part seems annoying

Comment: @Hans When developing the variance term, and keeping only the quadratic part, I am left with $\lambda (p'\Sigma p - p'\Sigma q - q'\Sigma p + q' \Sigma q)$. If I want to formulate it as $x' P x$, with $x = (p ; q)'$, I need to set $P = \left( (\Sigma ; -\Sigma) ; (-\Sigma ; \Sigma) \right)$ which is symmetric but not invertible... Am I doing something wrong or is this expected that $rank(P) = n$, not $2n$? For the linear part in $x$ that should be fine. I will work out the constraints later.

Comment: That is correct and expected.

Comment: How to tell if an objective function is nonlinear vs quadratic just by looking at it?

Comment: @develarist the presence of the absolute value in the objective function (from the transaction costs) makes it non-linear. It is already quadratic though due to the variance term of the form $x'\Sigma x$

Comment: so it's both non-linear and quadratic?

Comment: @JejeBelfort: I used to have perold's "large scale portfolio optimization" paper but I can't find it and it doesn't seem like it's obtainable for free from the net. If you can get your hands on that, it may be helpful but I'm not sure how helpful. Although, based on Hans' comments, it sounds like you're going in the right direction or maybe even quite close to solving it ? Definitely an interesting problem and I'm sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: @develarist: The jargon can be confusing but, in portfolio opt, quadratic would mean the $x^{\prime} \Sigma x$ and everything else linear. But, if you have the same term and then other things like absolute values, then it's termed non linear and of course much harder to solve. This is why it's nice to get a quadratic because there are some closed form solutions and straight forward solvers etc.

Comment: @markleeds thanks for the reference, I managed to get my eyes on it and it is very well written. Unfortunately though, it cannot help me reformulate my problem but there is an interesting part on the implementation side using sparse matrices, which I guess has been implemented in open-source quadratic optimization solvers. Thanks anyway, still need to work on the constraints and then implement the solution to see that it works. WIll update you on this ;)

Comment: Glad you found it. I  was hoping it would help you with your problem but atleast something about it was interesting.